# Best way to remove elements from display on a gameboard matrix in C++

Tags: c++, string, matrix, vector

I have a code that prints a 5x5 gameboard based on 25 input values entered by the user, OR 25 random numbers. What I would like to do next is, print a new gameboard after removing an element from it.

So the code asks the user to enter the (x, y) coordinates of the element to be removed from the board. After that, it would print a new gameboard without that element (=empty).

I'm still a beginner, so my code might be slightly messy. But it still works so far and I have spent much time making this. Any advice from advanced C++ developers is there some way to do this?

Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;
using Board = std::vector<vector<int>>;

const unsigned int BOARD_SIDE = 5;
const unsigned char EMPTY = ' ';

void initBoard(Board& board) { // start questions + vector formation

    while (true) {
            cout << "Select start (R for random, I for input): ";
            string start;
            cin >> start;
            if (start == "i" or start == "I") {
                cout << "Input: ";
                string input = "";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, input); // string input is now user input

                istringstream is { input }; // make 2D board vector from input numbers

                for (auto& row : board)
                {
                    for(auto& column : row)
                    {
                        is >> column;
                    }
                }
                break;
             }

             else if (start == "r" or start == "R") {
                cout << "Enter seed value: ";
                int seed;
                cin >> seed;

                srand(seed); // random number generator uses seed value entered by the user

                   ostringstream oss;
                   for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) // string length 25 numbers
                   {
                       if (i > 1)
                           oss << ' '; // numbers seperated with spaces after first number
                       oss << 1 + (rand() % 5); // number range 1-5
                   }
                   cin.ignore();
                   string randomString = oss.str(); // string randomString is now 25 random numbers

                   istringstream is { randomString }; // make 2D board vector from randomString numbers

                   for  (auto& row : board)
                   {
                       for (auto& column : row)
                       {
                           is >> column;
                       }
                   }
                   break;
             }
    }
}

void printBoard(const Board& board) { // prints a 2D board vector whose elements are vectors

    cout << "=================" << endl;
    cout << "|   | 1 2 3 4 5 |" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    for(unsigned int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIDE; ++row)
    {
        cout << "| " << row + 1 << " | ";
        for(unsigned int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIDE; ++column)
        {
            if(board.at(row).at(column) == 0)
            {
                cout << EMPTY << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << board.at(row).at(column) << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << "=================" << endl;
}

void printNewBoard(const Board& board) {
    printBoard(board);
}

int main()
{
    Board board(5, vector<int>(5)); // board is now 2D vector including 25 iser input OR random numbers
    initBoard(board);
    printBoard(board);

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter removable element (x, y): ";
        string remove;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, remove);

        printNewBoard(board);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your design is wrong (this is a matter of opinion of course) but you already have a `printBoard` function and you are trying to write a new function which uses that and does some other stuff (update the board). I would say that the important part here is updating the board. Write a function to do that, and then call that function and the `printBoard` function you already have from main, It doesn't seem to me that `printNewBoard` is an important enough operation to have its own function.

Comment: In any case its seems that the main task you have is to get the x and y coords from the `remove` string, everything else is trivial. I can see that you already have some code that extracts numbers from an istringstream, well you can use the same technique here. The only difference begin that here you have only two numbers.

Comment: Thank you John, appreciate your help and advices. I'll try this! - Toni